# Intel HAXM under a guest OS (Windows 10) running on Linux (KVM) crashes in Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, intel, haxm

Need help about Intel HAX which crashes under Windows 10 when running Windows 10 as a guest OS in a VM.

Some background information:

```
Hypervisor: KVM (virt-manager on ubuntu 16.10)
Guest operating system: Windows 10
Nested virtualization allowed
VT-X in Bios set
Intel HAX installed (latest version)
Android Studio (Version 6 as image for the Android emulator)
```

Problem:
When I run Android Studio and use Intel (x86) boot option to show up Android Emulator, Windows crashes completely. The error is a problem with a sys file of Intel HAX. Unfortunately I expected some wrong behavior of the Windows 10 running as VM with some nested virtualization components. In arm-mode I can start up the Android emulator but it's very slow. Is there a solution to use Google Intel (x86) Android image anyway? Some special key to start the emulator with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emulator is not really intended to be run in this configuration.  You can try several things:

- Run the emulator from the cmd line with the -no-accel flag.
- Uninstall HAXM.

Note that performance will not be very good.

If possible try to run the emulator in the linux host, or under a linux guest.

Comment: It works with the flag -no-accel. HAXM is then not running. I have also a development kit under Linux (Android Studio). I just was wondering if I could work with Xamarin in Visual Studio. The problem is now indeed the performance which is very poor. I think in a half year it will be possible ;)